# Why doesn't my label text change using NSDateFormatter stringFromDate?

Tags: ios, nsdateformatter

I've got a simple little test program --two labels and two buttons. When you hit either of the two buttons, the top label displays the currentTitle property of the appropriate button. The second label should display the time the button was tapped, but it comes up blank after erasing the original "Label" text.

The two NSLog statements work as expected.

```
- (IBAction)buttonHit:(id)sender
{
    DataClass *dataObject = [[DataClass alloc] init];
    UIButton *resultButton = (UIButton *)sender;
    dataObject.timeTapped = NSDate.date;
    dataObject.nameTapped = resultButton.currentTitle;

    self.nameLabel.text = dataObject.nameTapped;
    NSString *timeOfHit = [[NSString alloc] init];
    NSDateFormatter *formatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    timeOfHit = [formatter stringFromDate:dataObject.timeTapped];
    self.timeLabel.text = timeOfHit;


    NSLog(@"Button pressed was %@", dataObject.nameTapped);
    NSLog(@"Time pressed was %@", dataObject.timeTapped);

}
```

All help appreciated!

--Tim

Comment: Did you log timeOfHit?

Comment: BTW, this is wasted motion:  ` = [[NSString alloc] init]`.

Comment: @Hot Licks--Yes, it yields nothing. And thanks for the tip. I'm really green.

Comment: Ensure none of your objects are `nil`

Comment: If timeOfHit is nil then presumably stringFromDate failed for some reason.  The above code shouldn't fail, but if you've left out parts, the problem could be in the left-out parts.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason of blank  maybe is that you have not set the formatter's property. You can add one line code :

```
formatter.dateFormat = @"yyyy-MM-dd HH-mm-ss";
```

Comment: In theory there is a default format that should kick in.  I've never tried it, though.

Comment: @HotLicks I thought so, and I just took a try, find out that it will be blank without setting the date format.

Comment: That's good to know.  Not something you can figure out from the "excellent" documentation.